# How to sum date time from a CSV

Tags: python, csv, datetime, time, timedelta

I am trying to add up the time difference from a CSV file and print it in the console. What do I have to do for it?

The CSV file looks like this:

```
16:21,06:15,10:06
22:00,23:00,01:00
20:20,21:00,00:40
20:00,22:20,01:20
```

My Code so far:

```
import csv

with open("time.csv") as timedata:
   total = 0
   for row in csv.reader(timedata):
   total +=
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: you seem to have three values per column, so how do you want to calculate the time difference?

Comment: Hey, yes exactly

Comment: that was a question; if you have 3 values, you'll have to define how to calculate a difference

Comment: Hi FObersteiner, i want to sum up all values in the 3. column like this: 10:06 + 01:00 + 00:40 + 01:20

Answer (score 1):

I think it should solve your problem.

```
import csv

def toSeconds(t):
    return int(t.split(":")[0]) * 60 + int(t.split(":")[1])

def toTime(seconds):
    minutes = seconds // 60
    seconds = seconds % 60
    return str(minutes) + ":" + str(seconds)


with open("time.csv") as timedata:
    total = 0
    for row in csv.reader(timedata):
        for col in row:
            total += toSeconds(col)
    total = toTime(total)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, I get print(total) as an output of 291:10, but it's 13 hours and 04 minutes. do you know why that is?

Comment: do you use this csv file?
`16:21,06:15,10:06

22:00,23:00,01:00

20:20,21:00,00:40

20:00,22:20,01:20
`

Comment: Yes I used this csv